# why this MySql regular expression not working?

Tags: mysql, regex

```
SELECT 'AaYYY1231' REGEXP '[A-Z,0-9]+';
```

Result:

```
1
```

Why is it returning 1, when I expect it to return 0 ?
From where is is it finding match for 'a' ?

Comment: Why do you expect it to return 0? It only needs to find at least one character that matches the regex, anywhere in the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html

"REGEXP is not case sensitive, except when used with binary strings."

An example from the doc:

```
mysql> SELECT 'a' REGEXP 'A', 'a' REGEXP BINARY 'A';
+----------------+-----------------------+
| 'a' REGEXP 'A' | 'a' REGEXP BINARY 'A' |
+----------------+-----------------------+
|              1 |                     0 |
+----------------+-----------------------+
```

Additionally, it's not greedy, so it doesn't ensure that the entire string matches. Modifying the example above yields:

```
mysql> SELECT 'a' REGEXP BINARY '[A-Z0-9]+', 'Aa' REGEXP BINARY '[A-Z0-9]+';
+-------------------------------+--------------------------------+
| 'a' REGEXP BINARY '[A-Z0-9]+' | 'Aa' REGEXP BINARY '[A-Z0-9]+' |
+-------------------------------+--------------------------------+
|                             0 |                              1 |
+-------------------------------+--------------------------------+
```

To account for this, you can add flags for the beginning and end of the line:

```
mysql> SELECT 'Aa' REGEXP BINARY '^[A-Z0-9]+$';
+----------------------------------+
| 'Aa' REGEXP BINARY '^[A-Z0-9]+$' |
+----------------------------------+
|                                0 |
+----------------------------------+
```

This leads to the final answer of what you want:

```
mysql> SELECT 'AaYYY1231' REGEXP BINARY '^[A-Z,0-9]+$';
+------------------------------------------+
| 'AaYYY1231' REGEXP BINARY '^[A-Z,0-9]+$' |
+------------------------------------------+
|                                        0 |
+------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Bonus point, I wish I could give, for pointing out that it is not greedy.  Thank you.

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'BINARY'.

Comment: @KingRider I'd suggest posting your own repro -- including full input, output, and MySQL version -- as a fresh StackOverflow ticket. Note that the first example is directly from MySQL docs (both 5.1 at the time, and the current 5.7 to which the link redirects). Also, worth noting as a debugging tip, split your query onto multiple lines in order to get clearer feedback about which part of your query MySQL doesn't like.